# Dynamically add shipping methods for a specific shipping zone in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I am getting shipping information as a response from an api call. I already have a shipping zone setup with  zone name "United_States". I need to create shipping methods for this zone using info I get in response to the api call. Can someone show me (or point me to some relevant resources) how to create a new shipping method for a specific shipping zone. Here is the code I am using:

```
function handle_api_request() { 
...
...
...
 
if ($response_code === 200) {

    $response_data = json_decode($response, true);

    echo '<script>console.log("response in 200")</script>';

    if (is_array($response_data) && array_key_exists('shipments', $response_data)) {

        foreach ($response_data['shipments'] as $shipment) {

            $quotes = $shipment['quotes'];

            foreach ($quotes as $quote) {

                $shippingOption = $quote['shipping_option'];

                $price = (float) $quote['price'];
        
                // I need to create shipping method here using $shippingOption and $price
                // for my "United_states" shipping zone

            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error processing response data';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Request failed with status code: ' . $response_code;
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'custom_handle_api_request_on_checkout');
function custom_handle_api_request_on_checkout() {
... 
...
...
handle_api_request();
}
```

These are the shipping options and price i am able to parse from the API response:

> Shipping Option: USPS - PO Box , Price: 4.7064
>
> Shipping Option: UPS - Mail Innovations, Price: 4.7064
>
> Shipping Option: USPS Postal - BPM Parcels, Price: 4.7064
>
> Shipping Option: UPS - US Ground, Price: 17.3941
>
> Shipping Option: UPS - US 2nd Day Air, Price: 21.8532
>
> Shipping Option: UPS - US Next Day Air, Price: 45.769

Here is the raw response:

```
{
"subtotals": {
    "items": "6.6351",
    "fee": "1.8698",
    "app_fee": "0.0000"
},
"price": "8.5049",
"vat": "0.0000",
"currency": "USD",
"expire_date": "2023-08-09T22:45:02+00:00",
"shipments": [
    {
        "total_weight": "241",
        "items": [
            {
                "reference": "1"
            }
        ],
        "quotes": [
            {
                "quote": "92f14b53c493a41578b3fc55522243cee77320a2d5b72a898efccb564246cc69",
                "service": "Ground - Tracked",
                "shipping_level": "cp_ground",
                "shipping_option": "USPS Postal - BPM Parcels",
                "price": "4.7064",
                "vat": "0.0000",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "quote": "3ed6ac6c6257817f15be87634f622c2e5426a26b3de915572fe8764c340f1f2d",
                "service": "Ground - Tracked",
                "shipping_level": "cp_ground",
                "shipping_option": "USPS - PO Box ",
                "price": "4.7064",
                "vat": "0.0000",
                "currency": "USD"
            }

    }
],
"invoice_currency": "EUR",
"invoice_exchange_rate": "0.8825"
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear… We don't know what kind of shipping method you want to add, and you should provide in your question a functional example output for `$response_data`. Without that clarifications and example output, nobody can really be helpful.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. I have added the example response output. Hope this make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I can't really help as the listed shipping methods require a 3rd party plugin that certainly extend WooCommerce shipping method and related settings.